# LiveObjectDetection using Firebase MLKit in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I have integrated MLKit for object detection in my project. The sample project detects all objects but I want to detect only a specific object for example a watch and disregard other objects from detecting.

How can I do it in android?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the object detection API first, crop the detected object, and then pass it to an image classifier to see if it's a watch or other object of interest. For the image classifier portion you can use the [Image Labeling API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/label-images) within ML Kit, or you can create your own custom image classifier using [AutoML Vision Edge](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/automl-image-labeling).